# Can Camel be used as sterling RESTful webservice client?

Tags: rest, apache-camel

Say I would like to exploit Camel as a client to a RESTful web service. But not sure Camel is good enough for such kind of job. I also want to use http4 or ahc component, not cxf.

In general I need only two kinds of routes:

1. from Bean -> marshall to Json -> to Ahc with static URI -> unmarshall
   from Json -> to Bean. Example of static uri: `ahc:http://host/api/user/create`
2. from Bean -> marshall to Json -> to Ahc with dynamic URI -> unmarshall
   from Json -> to Bean. Example of dynamic uri: `ahc:http://host/api/user/id/1`

I imagine to have a service class to fire such a routes in a manner like:

```
UserService {

    @Autowired
    protected CamelContext restApiCamelContext;

    public UserCreateResponse createUser (UserModel user) {
        ... Camel's magick which starts create user route ...
    } 

    public UserModel getUserById (Long id) {        
        ... the id must be placed somehow into endpoint uri: http://host:port/api/user/id/${id} ...
        ... Camel's magick which get user by id ...
    }
}
```

The UserService is supposed to be used in Spring MVC controllers.

So, is it possible to implement such a UserService based on Camel's capabilities? If yes, then will it work good under high pressure of tons of user requests comming to a spring controller? Will it work fine with near hundred of different uris?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the request uri by setting the message header of CamelHttpUri dynamically.
If your business logic is simple, I think you can just create a simple camel route to do the job.
Then you using camel ProducerTemplate to send the request to the camel route.

Answer (score 0):

1. from Bean -> marshall to Json -> to Ahc with static URI ->
   unmarshall    from Json -> to Bean.
2. from Bean -> marshall to Json -> to 
   Ahc with dynamic URI -> unmarshall from Json -> to Bean.

Difference between CAMEL methods to() & recipientList() being that to-method cannot parse camel's dynamic parameters where as recipientList-method can.

```
from("restlet:/your/some/address/{sourceId}?restletMethods=GET")
.log("execute '${header.sourceId}' for something").to("log:WebRequestThroughput?groupSize=10")
.beanRef("yourServiceBeanRef", "serviceMethodName")
.marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
.to("http://domain/address/?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=true")
.unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, YourResponseObject.class)
.beanRef("anotherServiceBeanRef", "anotherMethodName");


from("restlet:/your/address/{sourceId}?restletMethods=GET")
.log("execute '${header.sourceId}' for something").to("log:WebRequestThroughput?groupSize=10")
.beanRef("yourServiceBeanRef", "serviceMethodName")
.marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant(HttpMethods.POST))
.recipientList(simple("http://domain/address/${header.sourceId}?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=true"))
.unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, YourResponseObject.class)
.beanRef("anotherServiceBeanRef", "anotherMethodName");
```